# initialize pointer member of structure gives seg fault

Tags: c, pointers

consider the struct

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
    const int *ptr;
}check;
```

in the main function

```
static check *p= NULL;
p = (check *)malloc(sizeof(check));
memset(p,0,sizeof(check));
```

now i  give values to some members [ thats why i memset to 0 so that all members are init]

```
int num = 10;
p->a = 1;
memcpy(p->ptr,&num,sizeof(int));
```

Result:
Segmentation fault

Question:
how do give value present at "num" and pass it to the ptr?

Comment: At no point in your code do you assign a value to `p->ptr` so it's an invalid pointer. You cannot `memcpy` into it

Comment: ptr is not initialized. It is pointing to an undefined address. In other words, there is no allocated object at the address pointed to by ptr.

Comment: `const`doesn't really makes sense for what you are trying to do. You want `int *ptr`.

Comment: `memcpy` is not what is needed to copy _the address_ of `num`:  `p->ptr  = &num` solves that.

Comment: NULL may not be a zero bit pattern on your architecture and compiler. The `memset` leaves `p` in an implementation defined state. This might become relevant again in the near future with ARM64 having tagged pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the actual storage for the integer (malloc), and make your pointer modifiable (remove const).

The line `memset(p,0,sizeof(check));` clears all fields of the `check` structure, including the pointer `ptr`.

Remove the `const` qualifier or you won't be able to modify `ptr`.

```
int num = 10;
p->a = 1;
p->ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));     // This line allocates memory to save an int
memcpy(p->ptr,&num,sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @Gardener Thats just wrong.  `memcpy` copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dst`. `sizeof(int)` yields the size of an int in bytes.

Comment: @Gardener Nowadays plain **ints** are mostly 32-bits not 64, so that will be 4 bytes compared to the 8 of the pointer. Good luck!

Comment: @Gardener I don't know where you get your info. Probably an outdated text book? The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) agrees with me, and so does the [glibc implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/i386/memcopy.h) of `memcpy`.